# Software for constant NAS replication

Tags: file-synchronization

I'm trying to build multiple NAS boxes in different locations. What I'm attempting to achieve is get a system in place that constantly replicates these NAS devices across the several devices.

Is there any suggestions on some software that I can run on 2 or more machines that will constantly sync the data on the NAS?

I've been looking at Parallel file systems but they tend to force the drives to not become 'ready' until replication is finished across all disks, I'm more chasing a background replication utility. Think behavior like OneDrive or Google Drive but instead of pointing to the remote cloud storage I want to link it to another device.

Comment: Are you looking at pushing outwards from a single master or at changes at either end being replicated?

Comment: Changes at either end being replicated :)